# Loading edges to neo4j taking too much time

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi I am trying to load edge files to neo4j of approximately 80000 records each. 
I am using:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
"file:///EdgesWriterSong_wrote.csv" AS csvLine
MATCH (writer:Writer { id: toInt(csvLine.WriterId),(songs:Songs { SongId: toInt(csvLine.SongId)
CREATE (writer)-[r:Wrote]->(songs)
```

It is taking way too much time to load. Is there a quicker way pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has syntax errors, but I will assume your actual code looks like this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///EdgesWriterSong_wrote.csv" AS csvLine
MATCH (writer:Writer { id: toInt(csvLine.WriterId) }),
  (songs:Songs { SongId: toInt(csvLine.SongId) })
CREATE (writer)-[r:Wrote]->(songs);
```

The most obvious reason for slowness for such a simple query would be that you have not yet created [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) for `:Writer(id)` and `Songs(SongId)`. Do that by running these 2 queries (one at a time):

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Writer(id);

CREATE INDEX ON :Songs(SongId);
```